# What gods were given offering in all Slavic nations?

Tags: slavic, worship

The Slavic god [Veles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veles_(god)#Sources) is said to be one of few gods where evidence is present to be given offering in all Slavic nations. Who are the other gods that were given offerings in all Slavic nations?

Comment: I think no god was given offering in all Slavic nations. Moravian and Bohemian pagans did not give offerings, they feasted in the god's name. The sages were fed by the people on regular basis, there was no need for offerings, because there was no church.

Comment: @NuloenTheSeeker ,  Even if you feast in a gods name, you can still give the gods offerings. In Greek Myth, giving an offering to a god could be as simple as saying a prayer and burning the offering.

Comment: Oh, yes people prayed to gods, but they would never go and burn something. It would be considered a waste, any "sacrifice" would be a waste. But I read that people decorated their "shrines". So if you consider that an offering, then there you go. All gods that held importance would have decorated shrines during certain times of the year. Lada and Mokosh, Perun and Svarog, Radegast, Morana(winter solstice was celebrating Morana), Veles. Every god would have decorated shrines if they were present. Sorry, But without sources I can't make it into an answer. I will try to find them.